# How to prevent Apache and use NGINX alone?

Tags: apache2, php, nginx

I've installed **Nginx** Mainline/Dev, **PHP 5.6** from **webupd8 repo** and **MariaDB 10**.

But with Software Updates/PHP update, Apache is being installed also.
How can I prevent this?

I just don't like apache and will use Nginx alone :).

I installed them with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/development
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-fpm php5-mysql php5-gd
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Paste the exact install commands you used into your question as an edit.

Comment: what does the command `dpkg -l | grep apache2` say?

Comment: Nothing.  Apache is not installed because I cancel the update when I saw Apache is being downloaded.

Comment: I think apache is bundled with the PHP update I got.

Comment: Nice, Thanks!
So what should I do first is:

sudo apt-get purge php5 php5-fpm php5-mysql php5-gd
....
Then what is the equivalent install command for PHP-FPM only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is somewhat two-fold.

---

The first problem is that that you use the `php5` package in your install.

That package is a metapackage - it pulls in other packages when you hit "Install".  The problem is it prefers the Apache plugins over `php5-fpm` and other processors, and causes Apache to install with everything else. (And this is not supposed to be the case, and I noticed this as a potential bug in the package and/or apt)

Use the same commands but drop `php5` from the install command.

First, remove any packages you've marked for install (it'll 'unmark'):

```
apt-get remove nginx php5 php5-fpm php5-mysql php5-gd mariadb-server phpmyadmin
```

Then reinstall them.

```
apt-get install nginx php5-fpm php5-mysql php5-gd mariadb-server phpmyadmin
```

---

The second problem is that the phpMyAdmin package has a similar recommendation on the Apache components.  I do not have the commands here but you'll need to override the installation options for apt to try and force it to NOT install the Apache packages.

---

Worst comes to worst, however, if phpMyAdmin requires Apache (which means the package is made incorrectly) you should be using Apache in place of nginx.

---

NOTE: As the PPA maintainer for the NGINX team, I recommend that you please use the stable PPA which has a newer version than the Mainline PPA at this time.  We are waiting for upstream changes (preferably a point release) in some third party modules before we can publish updates for the Mainline 1.9.x packaging to the PPA.  (1.8.x based on 1.7.x initially with additional updates is now the Stable release)

Comment: 1.9.x will likely land this weekend after I make some... packaging exceptions and additions... for the 1.9.x packaging.

Comment: And what is the right command to re-install them with the right package?

Comment: don't forget phpmyadmin looks like it depends on libapache2-mod-php5 which depends on apache2.2-common

Comment: @mchid That's true, in which case they should not be using phpMyAdmin or the php5 metapackages with nginx.

Comment: I guess you have wrong command for installation on your post @ThomasW.

Comment: Now I got this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RoldanLT/26536e30c77c699e3c24/raw/3c373e94fa0b54a3b0554f3d5b6924492b53b706/gistfile1.txt